# wordpress - unable the update the post attachments from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have two frontend forms to add and edit wordpress posts. I add form is working fine and was able to upload attachments as well perfectly.

The problem is with edit form. I am using the below code to upload the files, I am able to see in the db that new `attachment` post type records are appearing for the form submissions but the actual files are not getting uploaded and the `post_meta` is also not getting updated

```
  if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            }
            if ($_FILES) {
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                    }
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
                }
            }
            if ($attach_id > 0) {

                $type = get_post_mime_type($attach_id);
                if ($type = 'image/jpeg') {
                    update_post_meta($new_post, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
                } elseif ($type = 'video/mp4') {
                    update_post_meta($new_post, '_video_id', $attach_id);
                }
                //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            }
```

`$post_id` is the parent post ID for the attachment.

Comment: check the permission of your uploads directory

Comment: the permission shows 0755

Comment: try to add `if (empty($_FILES)) {echo "no file info";}` to your script to check if the array is empty.

Comment: no seems the array is not empty, I tried the other case also working `if ($_FILES) {echo "have file info";}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself. Since I have two file upload fields in the form I have been trying to upload only in the second field having the first field as empty.

For this empty field the `if` statement inside `foreach` loop is returning the error messages `upload error: 4`(which means [`No file uploaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)) and breaking the loop so I have added a `continue` ans changed the below part in my code.

```
if ($_FILES) {

                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {

                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $ermg = "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                        continue;
                    }else{
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
                }
                return $ermg;
                }
            }
```